# How to convert .las file to .pcd file using PDAL package in Python

Tags: python

I am using this command to convert .las to .pcd format `pdal translate input.las output.pcd`. But I am getting error while using this command `PDAL: Couldn't create writer stage of type 'writers.pcd'.` Please help me in solving this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you installed pdal? On which operating system? How do you run your command and where is python in there? It seems there is no pcd writer.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250714/converting-las-to-pcd-file-using-pdal

Answer (score 0):

- First, follow the quickstart instructions from PDAL website in order to be sure your environnement is correctly settled and all packages installed:
  https://pdal.io/quickstart.html
- Then, you can write a pipeline in a file named for example "pipeline.json"
  as follows:

```js
[
  {
    "type": "readers.las",
    "filename": "D:\\myLAS\\myFile.las"
  },
  {
    "type": "writers.pcd",
    "compression": "binary",
    "order": "X,Y,Z,intensity",
    "keep_unspecified": "false",
    "filename": "D:\\myPCD\\myFile.pcd"
  }
]
```

- You change the parameters "compression", "order" and "keep_unspecified" as wanted (https://pdal.io/stages/writers.pcd.html)
- Finally, you run your pipeline in **Anaconda command line**:

```js
pdal pipeline pipeline.json
```